# "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue" can be valid when returning from function?

Tags: c++, function, lvalue

Recently I was studying lvalue and rvalue concept.

When I do

```
int&z  = 0 ;
```

I get an expected error like :

```
initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
```

However, when I do this with a function that returns lvalue reference like:

```
int& get_value(){
    static int x = 10;
    return x;
}

//This line turns out to be valid...
get_value() = 20;
```

I wonder why `get_value() = 20;` is valid.

Comment: You are not declaring a reference in the second code.  Instead you are assigning to the returned reference from `get_value`.  You're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: In the second snippet the returned `int &` is initialized with `x` (in the `return x` line) which is an lvalue, so it's OK. The assignment `get_value() = 20` is irrelevant, it's not an initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message makes it quite clear:

> *initial* value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

(emphasis mine). So long as the reference is initially bound to an l-value, everything is fine (so long as you don't use a reference to a stack local variable, of course). The reference returned from `get_value` is bound to `x` which is an l-value, and that's allowed.

Without the function, you are essentially writing:

```
int x = 10;      // x is an l-value
int &get_x = x;  // just a variable instead of a function
get_x = 20;      // assignment is ok
```

which is clearly ok.